# Meaning of "course of the year"

Tags: phrases, verbs

I don't quite get the meaning of *course of the year* in the following sentence.

> They search for food by moving over ice from island to island during
>   the **course of the year**.

What does *course* mean here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Course* here means the passage of time, so "course of the year" means "throughout the year." See [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/course):

> the continuous passage or progress through time or a succession of
>   stages: in the course of a year; in the course of the battle.

Answer (score 7):

It means much the same as ‘during the year’, but perhaps empasizes the year’s movement from month to month and from season to season.